# How to work with background api calls like in Gmail?

Tags: android, push-notification

I would like to make api calls in background and show sometimes notifications due to api data. I had created service which make all calls:

```
class EndlessService : MyService() {

    private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null
    private var isServiceStarted = false

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        log("Some component want to bind with the service")
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        log("onStartCommand executed with startId: $startId")
        if (intent != null) {
            val action = intent.action
            log("using an intent with action $action")
            when (action) {
                Actions.START.name -> startService()
                Actions.STOP.name -> stopService()
                else -> log("This should never happen. No action in the received intent")
            }
        } else {
            log(
                "with a null intent. It has been probably restarted by the system."
            )
        }
        // by returning this we make sure the service is restarted if the system kills the service
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        log("The service has been created".uppercase(Locale.ROOT))
        startForeground(1, createNotification())
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        log("The service has been destroyed".uppercase(Locale.ROOT))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun startService() {
        if (isServiceStarted) return
        log("Starting the foreground service task")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service starting its task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        isServiceStarted = true
        setServiceState(this, ServiceState.STARTED)

        // we need this lock so our service gets not affected by Doze Mode
        wakeLock =
            (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "EndlessService::lock").apply {
                    acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/)
                }
            }

        // we're starting a loop in a coroutine
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isServiceStarted) {
                launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    pingFakeServer()
                }

                delay(10 * 60)
            }
            log("End of the loop for the service")
        }
    }

    private fun stopService() {
        log("Stopping the foreground service")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopping", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        try {
            wakeLock?.let {
                if (it.isHeld) {
                    it.release()
                }
            }
            stopForeground(true)
            stopSelf()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log("Service stopped without being started: ${e.message}")
        }
        isServiceStarted = false
        setServiceState(this, ServiceState.STOPPED)
    }

    private fun pingFakeServer() {
        
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val notificationChannelId = "ENDLESS SERVICE CHANNEL"

        // depending on the Android API that we're dealing with we will have
        // to use a specific method to create the notification
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager;
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Endless Service notifications channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN
            ).let {
                it.description = "Endless Service channel"
                it.enableLights(true)
                it.lightColor = Color.RED
                it.enableVibration(true)
                it.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                it
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
        }

        val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) Notification.Builder(
            this,
            notificationChannelId
        ) else Notification.Builder(this)

        return builder
            .setContentTitle("Endless Service")
            .setContentText("This is your favorite endless service working")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Ticker text")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN) // for under android 26 compatibility
            .build()
    }
}
```

then I added all info to the manifest and added classes for this service support:

```
enum class Actions {
    START,
    STOP
}

enum class ServiceState {
    STARTED,
    STOPPED,
}

private const val name = "SPYSERVICE_KEY"
private const val key = "SPYSERVICE_STATE"

fun setServiceState(context: Context, state: ServiceState) {
    val sharedPrefs = getPreferences(context)
    sharedPrefs.edit().let {
        it.putString(key, state.name)
        it.apply()
    }
}

fun getServiceState(context: Context): ServiceState {
    val sharedPrefs = getPreferences(context)
    val value = sharedPrefs.getString(key, ServiceState.STOPPED.name)
    return ServiceState.valueOf(value!!)
}

private fun getPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(name, 0)
}

and start it from an activity:

    override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            actionOnService(Actions.STOP)
        }
    
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            actionOnService(Actions.START)
        }
    
        private fun actionOnService(action: Actions) {
            if (getServiceState(this) == ServiceState.STOPPED && action == Actions.STOP) return
            Intent(this, EndlessService::class.java).also {
                it.action = action.name
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    log("Starting the service in >=26 Mode")
                    startForegroundService(it)
                    return
                }
                log("Starting the service in < 26 Mode")
                startService(it)
            }
        }
```

but as I see such way creates empty notification which can't be dismissed. Maybe I can use another way?

Comment: "ut as I see such way creates empty notification which can't be dismissed" -- a `Notification` is a requirement of a foreground service, and you need a foreground service to have the service run for more than a minute on Android 8.0 and higher. "Maybe I can use another way?" -- another way of *what*? As it stands, your code keeps the device CPU powered on indefinitely, and you are attempting to do work every 600 milliseconds. The `Notification` is the least of your concerns. Your bigger problem is the device killing your app to save on battery.

Comment: but for the example Gmail app as I see works all time. "Maybe I can use another way?" - another way of making requests to the api and with no notification. I read documentation  where saw also that foreground process need such notification, I thought about background service but as I know it is less effective than foreground one.

Comment: "but for the example Gmail app as I see works all time" -- first, that does not imply that Gmail is *running* all the time. Gmail most likely uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) or a proprietary equivalent. FCM and its predecessors (GCM, C2DM) have been around for a decade. Second, never compare yourself to Google. Google made the operating system. Google and the device manufacturers do not have to play by the same rules that you and I do.

Comment: yes, you are right. As I see that I have only such way of solving my problem. I agree that Google is great, but maybe their tricks are known) Thank you :D